# Process finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, build, android-ndk

Hi everyone I'm trying import Jumble into my project but this error appears in gradle of Jumble when I'm trying to compile the app first my NDK version was 17 but I read somewhere this error occurs in version 17 so I'm trying version 16 but the error still remains

```
Process 'command 'C:\dev\ndk\android-ndk-r16b\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

and my ndkBuild is Jumble gradle is :

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine project.android.ndkDirectory.absolutePath + '\\ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main/jni/').absolutePath
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

does anyone know how to fix this?
any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to invoke `ndk-build` yourself instead of just using `externalNativeBuild` as described in Google's documentation?

Comment: can you explain more about how can I do this?